# Using VBA to reference a cell in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an Excel macro using VBA and I have an input box to have the user select a "task". The entire row is then assigned variable "myCell". Then using "myCell", assign "SST" the value of cell "F" within that range. I'm new to coding so I'm a little stuck. Code so far is as follows:

```
Dim SST As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim Task As Range

Sheets("Sheets1").Activate
Set myCell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a task", Type:=8)
Set Task = myCell.EntireRow

SST = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Task).Cells(0, 6).Value
```

I have also tried it as:

```
SST = Range("F" & Task).Value
```

Neither seem to work. If you could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared SST as a Range so the correct syntax would be (since Task is already defined as a range itself)

`Set SST = Task.Cells(6)`

If you want it to be assigned the value change the declaration to Variant (or whatever) and use

`SST = Task.Cells(6).value`